# woocommerce_order_status_completed not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a piece of code for creating video passes after someone buys a product with the ID 1136. For some reason, the order_status_completed is not doing anything. I tried hooking the function to woocommerce_thankyou and woocommerce_payment_complete. I am at a loss. I ran the code without hooking it to an action and it works fine. No bugs in my error log.. nothing.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed','create_video_passes',10,1);


function create_video_passes($orderId){
    

    $order = wc_get_order($orderId);
    
    $orderData = $order->get_data();



foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ):

$item = $item->get_data();
if($item['id'] == 1136){
    
    foreach(range(1,$item['quantity']) as $index) {
        
        $passArray = array(
          'post_title'      => generateRandomString(),
          'post_type'       => 'videopass',
          'post_status'     => 'publish',
          'post_author'     => 1
        );
         
        // Insert the post into the database
        $passId = wp_insert_post( $passArray );
        update_post_meta( $passId, 'gebruikt','nee');
        update_post_meta( $passId, 'email',$orderData['billing']['email']);     
        
    }


}


endforeach;
    
}
```

Comment: Is the hook not working or is the function not working? Have you tried doing anything else inside the function to verify if it works and narrow down the issue?

Comment: So, narrowed it down. Printed order data from wc_get_order into a field:

O:44:"AutomatticWooCommerceAdminOverridesOrder":1:{s:5:"�*�id";i:1208;}

Comment: So the hook is working, there's just something incorrect about the code inside it. Unfortunately that's where WordPress knowledge is no longer useful, and you need to know the proper WooCommerce APIs to use, and that makes this off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must try changing $item['id'] to this

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item )
{
$product = $item->get_data();
$item_id = $item->get_product_id();
 if( $item_id == 1136 )
  {
    // Keep Your code here. 
  }
}
```

Keep Posted.

Answer (score 0):

$item['id'] should be $item['product_id']